# Sockets don't close immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, window

I have a script which opens a socket, reads some data and then shutsdown and closes the socket.

If I put this script on a loop I get an error telling me the socket is still in use and I can't create another socket on this particular port.

How do I force a socket to shutdown to open the port for a new socket to be created?

Pastebin here:

```
 while True: 
     anchor = AnchorIO("192.168.2.11")
     raw = anchor.read(request=True)
     data = raw.astype(np.float32).view(np.complex64)
     data = data.reshape((-1, 4))
     savemat("test_r1_"+str(i)+".mat", {"data": data})
     anchor._cmd_sock.shutdown()
     anchor._data_sock.shutdown()
     anchor._cmd_sock.close()
     anchor._data_sock.close()
```

https://pastebin.com/1nZQ5r7V

(this is on windows 10)

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I uploaded it here: https://pastebin.com/1nZQ5r7V I didn't want to change anything but basically it opens a socket, does some communication, closes it and attempts to open it again. But the port number is listed as still in use.